${}$Doppler shift
If observer is moving and source is at rest then i can treat the scenario with approach in which observer is at rest and source is moving since this is what will be happening according to the observer and in other scenario in which the observer is at rest and source is moving then this is going to be the same as before therefore the new frequency should be same in both cases but in Doppler's equations its not the case(when observer is moving the new frequency is old frequency times a expression and when the source is moving the new frequency is old frequency times reciprocal of that expression) so what's the reason
Furthermore, in real situations whether i am going to measure same frequency shifts in both cases or it will be according to the doppler's equations, if it will be according to doppler's equation then why?

Mechanical or electromagnetic waves?

Please use proper sentences.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The form of the Doppler shift tells you a lot about your system.
If the equations are symmetric in transmit (Tx) and receive (Rx), then all motion is relative and there is no preferred rest frame.
If they are not, then there is a preferred frame that may be called "the rest frame", and that frame is of course the rest frame of the medium in which the waves propagate.
Note that this principle is sufficient to derive Einsteins theory of special relativity. See: Bondi's $k$-calculus.
